# how to pass the variable product.tpl or modal.tpl in in prestashoap 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem that I can not solve. in prestashop 1.7 I have a tpl file called product.tpl where inside, besides the various data, I call a file with the following code:

```
`{block name='product_variants'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl'}
              {/block}
{block name='product_miniature_item'}
  <article class="product-miniature js-product-miniature" data-id-product="{$product.id_product}" data-id-product-attribute="{$product.id_product_attribute}" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      {block name='product_thumbnail'}
        <a href="{$product.url}" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">
          <img
            src = "{$product.cover.bySize.home_default.url}"
            alt = "{if !empty($product.cover.legend)}{$product.cover.legend}{else}{$product.name|truncate:30:'...'}{/if}"
            data-full-size-image-url = "{$product.cover.large.url}"
          >
        </a>
      {/block}

      <div class="product-description">
        {block name='product_name'}
          <h1 class="h3 product-title" itemprop="name"><a href="{$product.url}">{$product.name|truncate:30:'...'}</a></h1>
        {/block}

        {block name='product_price_and_shipping'}
          {if $product.show_price}
            <div class="product-price-and-shipping">
              {if $product.has_discount}
                {hook h='displayProductPriceBlock' product=$product type="old_price"}

                <span class="sr-only">{l s='Regular price' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</span>
                <span class="regular-price">{$product.regular_price}</span>
                {if $product.discount_type === 'percentage'}
                  <span class="discount-percentage">{$product.discount_percentage}</span>
                {/if}
              {/if}

              {hook h='displayProductPriceBlock' product=$product type="before_price"}

              <span class="sr-only">{l s='Price' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</span>
              <span itemprop="price" class="price">{$product.price}</span>

              {hook h='displayProductPriceBlock' product=$product type='unit_price'}

              {hook h='displayProductPriceBlock' product=$product type='weight'}



            <div class="add">  
                <form action="{$urls.pages.cart}" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" value="{$product.id_product}" name="id_product">
                  <!--<input type="number" style="padding: 3px 13px; float:left; width:30%; margin-left: 10px;" class="input-group form-control" name="qty" min="1" value="1">-->

                <a style="cursor: pointer; padding: 3px 13px; margin-left: 10px; background: #ff9600; color: #fff;" data-button-action="add-to-cart" class="addtocart-btn"
                   {if !$product.add_to_cart_url}
                    disabled
                  {/if}>
                <i class="material-icons shopping-cart">&#xE547;</i>

            {l s='Add' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}



                  <a href="{$product.url}" style=" padding: 3px 13px; margin-left: 10px;"  class="view-dtls-btn">


                    {if {$language.iso_code} === 'ar'}

                        {l s='رأي' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}

                    {else}
                            {l s='View' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
                    {/if} 
                    </a>

          </form>   
            </div>  


            </div>
          {/if}
        {/block}

        {block name='product_reviews'}
          {hook h='displayProductListReviews' product=$product}
        {/block}
      </div>

      {block name='product_flags'}
        <ul class="product-flags">
          {foreach from=$product.flags item=flag}
            <li class="product-flag {$flag.type}">{$flag.label}</li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {/block}

      <div class="highlighted-informations{if !$product.main_variants} no-variants{/if} hidden-sm-down">
        {block name='quick_view'}
          <a class="quick-view" href="#" data-link-action="quickview">
            <i class="material-icons search">&#xE8B6;</i> {l s='Quick view' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
          </a>
        {/block}

        {block name='product_variants'}
          {if $product.main_variants}
            {include file='catalog/_partials/variant-links.tpl' variants=$product.main_variants}
          {/if}
        {/block}
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
{/block}`
```

and everything works correctly.
what interests me most specifically is the portion of code referred to in this block

```
 {block name='product_variants'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl'}
              {/block}
```

The code is:

```
`<div class="product-variants">
  {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
    <div class="clearfix product-variants-item">
      <span class="control-label">{$group.name}</span>
      {if $group.group_type == 'select'}
        <select
          class="form-control form-control-select"
          id="group_{$id_attribute_group}"
          data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
          name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <option value="{$id_attribute}" title="{$group_attribute.name}"{if $group_attribute.selected} selected="selected"{/if}>{$group_attribute.name}</option>
          {/foreach}
        </select>
      {elseif $group.group_type == 'color'}
        <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
              <label>
                <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span
                  {if $group_attribute.html_color_code}class="color" style="background-color: {$group_attribute.html_color_code}" {/if}
                  {if $group_attribute.texture}class="color texture" style="background-image: url({$group_attribute.texture})" {/if}
                ><span class="sr-only">{$group_attribute.name}</span></span>
              </label>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}
        <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <li class="input-container float-xs-left">
              <label>
                <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {/if}
    </div>
  {/foreach}
</div>`
then I modified the tpl file of the module product.tpl and modal.tpl and inside the main file "product.tpl and modal.tpl", inside the foreach I inserted a part of the code to display the variants and some product html design.

what happens is that I visualize perfectly the formatting but all the values ​​of the variants do not let me see them, specifically this portion of code does not work`<div class="product-variants">
  {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
    <div class="clearfix product-variants-item">
      <span class="control-label">{$group.name}</span>
      {if $group.group_type == 'select'}
        <select
          class="form-control form-control-select"
          id="group_{$id_attribute_group}"
          data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
          name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <option value="{$id_attribute}" title="{$group_attribute.name}"{if $group_attribute.selected} selected="selected"{/if}>{$group_attribute.name}</option>
          {/foreach}
        </select>
      {elseif $group.group_type == 'color'}
        <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
              <label>
                <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span
                  {if $group_attribute.html_color_code}class="color" style="background-color: {$group_attribute.html_color_code}" {/if}
                  {if $group_attribute.texture}class="color texture" style="background-image: url({$group_attribute.texture})" {/if}
                ><span class="sr-only">{$group_attribute.name}</span></span>
              </label>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}
        <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <li class="input-container float-xs-left">
              <label>
                <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {/if}
    </div>
  {/foreach}
</div>`
```

Obviously the same code in the product page recalls all the variables, while in the home where I recall the contents on the homepage I can not recover them. Where am I wrong? I put hands on prestashop only a few weeks ago and I think I have a confused ideas. I hope little I have been clear, thanks to those who have the patience to answer.
  or optional we want to pass the $groups variable in modal.tpl inside  ps_shoppingcart please help me..
thnx in advance

Comment: {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl' groups=$groups}

Comment: where we put this line of code bcoz we want use the $grops variable in modal.tpl in ps_shopingcart